# Is it possible to use `nuxt-icon` package in my standalone vue3 project?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, icons

I wanna use these icons provided by this package https://nuxt.com/modules/icon.

but importing from the package causes this error:
`ReferenceError: process is not defined`

I know the code is meant to be run in a JavaScript backend environment, but i was wondering if there are alternatives or work arounds regarding this.